# hide fields using html div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am very much new to Javascript but was hoping someone could advise with the following problem.
I have the following div class and a part of the requirement is to hide the entire div and all its sub h2 fields if the {retreat_dates} field is missing, can someone please point me to the right direction?

```
    <div class="grid_3 retreatextradetails">

        <h2>Retreat dates</h2>
        <p>
        {retreat_dates}{date}<br />{/retreat_dates} 
        </p>
        <div class="hr"></div>
        <h2>Age range</h2>
        <p>{retreat_age}</p>

        <div class="hr"></div>

        <h2>Fitness level</h2>
        <p>{retreat_fitness}</p>

        <div class="hr"></div>

        <h2>No. of places</h2>
        <p>{retreat_places}</p>

        <div class="hr"></div>

        <h2>Retreat Prices</h2>
        <table>
        {retreat_prices}
        <tr>
            <td class="cell_title">{description}</td>
            <td class="price">{price}></td>
        </tr>
        {/retreat_prices}
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is the corresponding javascript i am using but it does not work:

```
</script>
$("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
    var search = this.value;
    $(".grid_3 retreatextradetails").show().filter(function () {
        return $(".retreat_dates", this).text().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();        
});
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: You can do this server-side as well (as long as you don't need this to be dynamic). What are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to hide the H2's if the entire element is hidden ?

Comment: If you hide the entire div, then everything inside it will be hidden, include the `h2` and all the child elements! Then whats the point of hidding the `sub h2 fields`??

Comment: What is `{retreat_dates}`?  By "missing" I can only assume that it's populated by some server-side processing.  That server-side processing should be where you determine whether or not to emit the `div` to the client.  It has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Helo guys, yes but how do i hide the entire div? I also need to make that conditional check to see if one of the fields is populated...

Comment: @ Radu, i am using expression engine

Comment: If you don't go the server side route (which would be the best way as it would mean less markup rendered on your page) can you use jquery or does it need to be pure js?

Comment: looks like it it can use jquery, <script src="/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: i have pasted some of hte javascript i am using, but it is not functioning the way i wish it to, can anyone spot anything obvious?

Comment: you forgot the `.` on retreatextradetails and I wouldn't bother with the `.grid3`

Comment: Your selector is wrong. Should be `$('.grid_3.retreatextradetails')`. Also, where is the element with the class `retreat_dates` in HTML? Generated by the server?

Comment: @travesty3 yes some of the elements are populated by the server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add function in javascript file after try it .

```
$('.retreatextradetails').find("h2").each(function() {
    if($(this).next('p').html().trim().indexOf("{retreat_dates}")==-1){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next('p').hide();
        $(this).next('div').hide();

    }

});
```

hope it's help for you .

Comment: this is very close to what i require, however rather than do a string comparison, i would like to simply check if that field is populated with anything, can this be done?

Comment: can you please give me more explanation because i'm confuse what you actual needed ?

Comment: this {retreat_dates} is a macro and is dynamically replaced with strings, your code above appears to work but rather than do a string comparison for this macro, i simply need to check if that field is populated with anything

Comment: i think this might be it if($(this).next('p').html().trim().indexOf(search) < 0)

Answer (score 2):

as you can use jquery I would do the following:

give the p holding the dates some sort of classname - eg `<p class="rdates">`

then you can use the following jquery on document ready

```
$('.retreatextradetails').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('.rdates:eq(0)').text().trim() == "") {
       $(this).hide(); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UtS6v/

**UPDATE**

I have changed my answer to match your provided js

```
$('#filterBox').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $('.retreatextradetails').hide();
    $('.rdates:contains("' + search + '")').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UtS6v/4/

Mixture of the two using the p selector:  http://jsfiddle.net/UtS6v/6/

Comment: Question for OP on this answer, could the `{date}` be populated when the `{retreat_dates}` is not?

Comment: I assumed the date was each retreat date

Comment: the retreat_dates is populated dynamically, so we would need to do a check on this

Comment: I would suggest you use [jQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/). Some browsers don't have a built-in `trim()` function.

Comment: this solution is close to what i need but can we do a check against the <p> tag instead?

Comment: if the order of your `p`s is always going to be the same you can use the selector `p:eq(0)` but that would only work in my first answer

Answer (score 1):

Lets begin by parts.

1. To hide a DOM element in jQuery you use .hide(), to show it again
   .show() so $("yourSelector").hide() should hide all elements found
   by "yourSelector"
2. Selectors are the most powerfull tool in jQuery, you should master
   them
3. You can use tools like [jquery-debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi) (a chrome development
   tool extension which allows you to try your selector in any page
   with jQuery on it)
4. Last example seems very similar what you need, if you need something
   else, ask and I will try to help.

Comment: With all due respect, this is not a very useful answer, IMO. 1: He already seems to know about `show()` and `hide()`, as he is already using them in his provided code. 2: Doesn't help to answer the question at all. 3: While that extension may be helpful, you don't really need any extensions to try your selector, just use the built-in dev tools of almost any browser (I suggest Chrome) and `console.debug()`. 4: Not part of an answer.